# Loading different data frames in multiple threads at the same

Tags: python, multithreading, flask

I have a flask server which executes read and write queries on data frames. I have a caching mechanism (using cacheout library) to cache the data frames when i receive a request, then using the cached data frame upon receiving request for the same data frame.

Currently i am using a lock which makes all threads load their (different) data frame sequentially and then process the loaded data frame further.

What i would like is that when i receive multiple requests for different data frames, each thread (for each request) should load the data frame (using pandas.read_excel) simultaneously into the memory and not sequentially.

Currently i am using a simple lock which ensures that the same data frame is not loaded twice, but i need to load multiple data frames in parallel as well.

`def read_query_request(query, file_path, sheet_name, source_id):
    logger.info('Handling read request for source ' + sheet_name + '_' + source_id)

```
try:
    data_frame_identifier = sheet_name + '_' + source_id

    # Load df with lock ensuring data frame loads only once.
    with lock:
        start_l=time.time()
        load_data_frame(file_path, sheet_name, source_id)
        end_l=time.time()
        logger.info('BENCHMARKING INFO: Read Request, Data frame load time ---' + str(end_l - start_l))

    #cache_state()
    # Executing query on loaded data frame
    # sheetName = getSheetName( query )
    query = query.replace('dataframe', data_frame_identifier)
    start_e = time.time()
    queryResult = ps.sqldf(query)
    end_e = time.time()
    logger.info('BENCHMARKING INFO: Read Request, psql query execution time ---' + str(end_e - start_e))

    start_j = time.time()
    queryResult = queryResult.to_json(orient='records')
    res = {"isErrored":"False", "results": json.loads(queryResult)}
    result = json.dumps(res)
    end_j = time.time()
    logger.info('BENCHMARKING INFO: Read Request, json conversion time ---' + str(end_j - start_j))

    logger.info(LRU_cache.keys())
    return result`
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from your code you are using one lock for your whole app, which limits to only one dataframe processing a time and you would like to process multiple in a parallel. To get started, threads in Python (because of the [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock)) can't be run in a parallel and would be run in a sequence. So if you want parallel execution you would need a multi-processing. Simplest to implement is to use stdlib's [multiprocessing pool](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers). But you still need some synchronization to avoid processing more than one df at a time. To do so, you can keep a registry of what df are currently processed:

```
...
registry_change_lock = Lock()
registry = set()  # you can use list, but search in list is O(n) and in set is O(1)
while True:
    registry_change_lock.acquire()
    if source_id in registry:
        # This id is already processed, release the lock 
        # to let other threads register their ids and avoid 
        # deadlocks
        registry_change_lock.release()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        continue
    else:
        registry.add(source_id)
        registry_change_lock.release()
```

P.S. This is not the only way to solve your problem, but one of the easier ones.